# SU pycharm launch as superuser?

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, su

i need to work on pycharm as superuser, however when i run it it doesn't give me the permissions , so how to launch pycharm which was installed from Ubuntu software center, as super user su ?
Thank you in advance

Comment: what permission you require which are not available as a super user ? the administrative elevated run gives the process absolute permissions.

Comment: yep , but when i run some program it says you dont have permission